# Mysql - records from last 30 days, but 1 and 2 months ago

Tags: mysql, date, time

This query is selecting rows applied last 30 days:

```
SELECT `amount` FROM `mg_inputs` WHERE `amount`<0 AND `product`='144' AND DATE(firstedit) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

How about queries selecting rows applied last 30 days, but 1 month ago (between: today-30days and today-60days)? Same question goes for "2 months ago". Nothing is working for me at all (SQL is returning errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important thing to note here is that not all months are 30 days, so instead of using `INTERVAL DAY` use `INTERVAL MONTH`.

Next, you don't need to use the subtraction sign for dates, you can use the [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) function which will do what you need.

Last, keeping those things in mind, you can use the `BETWEEN` operator to check for rows within a date range. So, for example, if you want all rows from one month ago, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

You should note that for the `BETWEEN` operator to work properly, the older date must appear first. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d2da/3) example that demonstrates that.